# How to resolve incorrect SQL syntax error when using "Dimension Lookup / Update" with MySql?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector, kettle

I'm using Kettle 4.1 with MySql 5.6 and am trying to run the chapter 4 [demo](http://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/77/04706351/DOWNLOAD/635179_downloads.zip) from the [Pentaho Kettle Solutions: Building Open Source ETL Solutions with Pentaho Data Integration](http://ca.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470635177.html) and am having the  ["Dimension Lookup / Update" step](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Dimension+Lookup-Update) fails with the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=1' at line 1

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to [upgrade the version MySql Connector that Kettle is using](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?94086). Go to your Kettle installation's `libext\JDBC` folder and replace `mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar` with a newer version of Connector/J downloaded from [MySql's site](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). Just extract the newer version from the zip and copy it over and *delete* the older version. Then rerun and it should work.

Personally, it failed with version `5.1.6` of the Connector, but it worked with `5.1.23` (the currently lastest version) YMMV.

Comment: When you ask a question there is checkbox at the bottom that says "Answer Own Question". I had searched SO and didn't find the answer, but then found it elsewhere (linked in my answer) and so I brought it back here for the benefit of others.